# Apple's Swift implementation on Windows

Tags: swift, gnu, gnustep

I came across an open source implementation of the Swift compiler at `https://source.ind.ie/project/phoenix`. However as you can see from the code, it was build as an Xcode project (Mac). How can I compile it in GNUstep under Windows/Linux/Unix?

If I can't run it outside Mac/Xcode, it really no point of having an open source implementation of Swift, isn't it?

Comment: Of course there's a point. From the README: *Phoenix is a free and open source implementation of the Swift language.* If you want it to run under Windows, you may have a lot of work to do, but at least you have the option of doing it and, if you like, sharing your work with others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this project? http://elementscompiler.com/elements/silver/

They are trying to write a compiler that will let you write Swift on Windows and Android but they say it is not a cross-compiler so I am unsure how much of your "Windows Swift" code would work on Mac.

Comment: I doubt Phoenix is cross-compiler too.